# How to upload to Google Cloud Storage buckets from an iOS app via Service Account Authentication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to upload files from an iOS app into Google Cloud Storage buckets via Service Account Authentication i.e. without user consent.

The samples at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Samples don't contain a project for Cloud Storage. The samples present there only use standard OAuth 2.0 authentication with user consent.

What I know is that *GTLServiceStorage* with *GTLQueryStorage* need to be used, but the authentication part is unclear.

Comment: Hi @Andras, you've found the solution to this problem yet? I have same problem.

Comment: @cuGoku Did ANY of you find out anything? :/

Comment: Unfortunately not; I switched to AWS.

Comment: They do contains a project for Cloud Storage now. https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/tree/master/Examples/StorageSample